# How to Secure the Node-red using GCP Oauth 2.0?

Tags: node-red

I want my node-red to authenticate users using GCP Oauth service to view dashboard and editor. I have searched for the web, but I haven't found anything useful yet to start. I would really appreciate if you guys can point that way/direction. Is it possible to include role-based access users to access dashboard and editor?

Thanks
Prudhvi

Answer (score 0):

The Node-RED [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#oauthopenid-based-authentication) have details of how to setup oAuth based authentication for the editor, You will need a passportJS Auth [Strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/)

Currently the Dashboard UI only support Basic HTTP Auth.